# Scrape data from European Parliament website

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I need to collect some information about the members of the European Parliament. I select CSS class using the inspector tools of Google Chrome.

Specifically the class ".sln-additional.info" store the information about the Party and the country of each members of the parliament.

```
url <- "https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/it/full-list/all"
html <- read_html(url)

info_hmtl <- html_elements(html,".sln-additional-info")
info <- html_text(info_hmtl)
```

all that information are stored in three rows for each members. I need to be stored in three columns.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the output you've got as input to a `matrix()` using `ncol=3` and `byrow=TRUE`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/it/full-list/all"
h <- read_html(url)
mem_names <- h %>% html_elements("div.erpl_title-h4.t-item") %>% html_text()
addl_info <- h %>% html_elements(".sln-additional-info") %>% html_text() %>% matrix(., ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
res <- cbind(mem_names, addl_info)
head(res)
#>      mem_names            
#> [1,] "Magdalena ADAMOWICZ"
#> [2,] "Asim ADEMOV"        
#> [3,] "Isabella ADINOLFI"  
#> [4,] "Matteo ADINOLFI"    
#> [5,] "Alex AGIUS SALIBA"  
#> [6,] "Mazaly AGUILAR"     
#>                                                                                           
#> [1,] "Gruppo del Partito popolare europeo (Democratici cristiani)"                        
#> [2,] "Gruppo del Partito popolare europeo (Democratici cristiani)"                        
#> [3,] "Gruppo del Partito popolare europeo (Democratici cristiani)"                        
#> [4,] "Gruppo Identità e Democrazia"                                                       
#> [5,] "Gruppo dell'Alleanza progressista di Socialisti e Democratici al Parlamento Europeo"
#> [6,] "Gruppo dei Conservatori e Riformisti europei"                                       
#>                                                                
#> [1,] "Polonia"  "Independent"                                  
#> [2,] "Bulgaria" "Citizens for European Development of Bulgaria"
#> [3,] "Italia"   "Forza Italia"                                 
#> [4,] "Italia"   "Lega"                                         
#> [5,] "Malta"    "Partit Laburista"                             
#> [6,] "Spagna"   "VOX"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>